# Easiest method to check network status on iPad with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I would like to check the network status on the iPad with Adobe Air, at this moment i am checking by sending a URLREQUEST to Google.com. Is there any other better way to monitor the network status, and know if there is a connection or connection have been dropped. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tricky part here we are not ping some interval times. so we use

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.NETWORK_CHANGE, onNetwork_ChangeHandler);
```

It will trigger when ever change net status change so performance wise also good.

Because Ping is very costly operation.So call start() URLMontior after network changed triggered then we call stop().

```
      package com.abc.net
    {
    import air.net.URLMonitor;
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.StatusEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    [Event(name="networkStatusChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]
    public class NetStatusMonitor extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var urlMonitor:URLMonitor;
        private var url:String;

        public function KBNetStatusMonitor(url:String = 'http://www.adobe.com')
        {
            super();
            this.url = url;
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.NETWORK_CHANGE, onNetwork_ChangeHandler);
        }

        protected function onNetwork_ChangeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            start();
        }       

        public function start():void
        {
            urlMonitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest(url));
            urlMonitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onNetStatus_ChangeHandler);

            if(!urlMonitor.running)
                urlMonitor.start();
        }

        public function stop():void
        {
            if(urlMonitor.running)
                urlMonitor.stop();
        }

        private function onNetStatus_ChangeHandler(event:StatusEvent):void
        {
            trace("event code " + event.code);
            trace("event level " + event.level);
            dispatchEvent(new NetStatusEvent(NetStatusEvent.NETWORK_STATUS_CHANGED,urlMonitor.available));
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Event Class

```
package com.abc.net
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class NetStatusEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const  NETWORK_STATUS_CHANGED:String = "networkStatusChanged";

        public var status:Boolean;

        public function NetStatusEvent(type:String, status:Boolean, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this.status = status;
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new NetStatusEvent(type, status, bubbles,cancelable);
        }

    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var netStatusMonitor:NetStatusMonitor = new NetStatusMonitor();
    netStatusMonitor.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NETWORK_STATUS_CHANGED,function(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
           statusCallBack.call(null,event.status);
});

netStatusMonitor.start();
```

Comment: I did actually used this URL monitor before, maybe i should keep use it. Thanks Raja!!

Comment: Please look at top.I 'm added few point about Event.NETWORK_CHANGE.

Comment: Sweet that's what i am after!